# Node.JS: test code vs. production code organization

Tags: node.js, unit-testing

From a cursory look in several node.js projects on Github I noticed that the common convention is to put test files under a `./spec` directory (exact name may vary: `./tests`, `./specs`, etc.). Let's call this the "classic" project organization.

On the other hand, there is also (at least theoretically) the "localizing" organization: each test file is in the same directory as the production file it tests (e.g., under `./controllers` we will have `login_controller.js` as well as `login_controller.spec.js`).

In order to avoid theological battles on this clearly subjective topic I will ask concrete questions:

- Has anyone saw major modules/apps using the localizing organization?
- Are there hard drawbacks/limitations to the localizing organization? by "hard" I mean something along the lines of "well, Heroku does not include the specs/ directory in its deployment bundle (a.k.a slug) so the classic organization has a smaller footprint on the server".
- Are there testing frameworks (Mocha, jasmine-node, and co.) that somehow impose the "classic" scheme?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. No, but that is up to your organizational preference. I personally would prefer a test directory.
2. Nope. Heroku includes everything in your slug that it receives, the only things that are excluded are the ones excluded from git in your .gitignore file.
3. Not 100% sure, but generally no, test frameworks do not impose a structure on your code. They simply provide the tools for you to write your tests using the structure you want.

Answer (score 3):

Consistency here is more important than the direction you decide to go. There are a few relatively minor issues that I see going with test files next to source files.

1. Potential code navigation issues. I could see you sometimes opening
   the wrong file on accident. Opening the test file when you mean to
   open the source file, etc. This would happen more often if those
   files are side by side and the only difference is .spec in the
   filename.
2. Potential issues with unit test runner. Most unit test runners seem
   to prefer a folder of tests by default. I'm sure you could configure
   them to look across the entire project, but it depends on the test
   runner.
3. Potentially slower unit test automation. Since your test files are
   mixed across your entire project, the test runner will have to scan
   your entire project for test files instead of a dedicated directory.
   For a large code base, this could mean it takes longer for your test
   suite to complete. Chances are the difference in speed is quite
   small however.

As I said, these are minor issues and you can definitely work around them, but it does add some friction. You have to weigh the potential downsides with what you see as the benefits of having your test files reside next to your source files.